# What python data structure should I use to store multi-dimensional fantasy football data

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a list containing data on 600 or so football (soccer) players. Each players in the list is stored as a dictionary, with each attribute stored as for example

```
{'goals scored': 5}
```

In the dictionary as the total player stats over the course of the season.
However there is also a nested list with a key termed `history` in each player dictionary which contains individual game data for the player such that:

```
{'history': list of game weeks}
```

With each element in the list containing another dictionary with player statistics for that game.

I am mostly interested in extracting the individual game player data, and potentially running some analysis on the players. However in order to do this I need a solid data structure into which to extract each individual game's statistics, whilst retaining the player ID: a list of dictionaries where the keys are the player IDs and the values are a list of the individual games containing dictionaries of the player stats for that game. However I'm not sure whether this will translate well into a pandas dataframe, which is ultimately where I would like to perform most of my analysis.

Does anyone have any recommendations for python libraries/data structures which are good for multi-dimensional data such as those described here ( where the dimensions are 1) Individual player ID 2) Individual game week ID and 3) Individual game statistics).

EDIT: sample player data: the first dictionary contains overall data for the season, then under the key 'history' we have a list of all the individual games, with a dictionary containing the stats for each game.

```
{u'assists': 0,
 u'bonus': 0,
 u'bps': 0,
 u'creativity': u'0.0',
 u'dreamteam_count': 0,
 u'ea_index': 56,
 u'element_type': 1,
 u'ep_next': u'0.5',
 u'ep_this': u'1.5',
 u'event_points': 0,
 u'first_name': u'David',
 u'form': u'0.0',
 u'goals_conceded': 0,
 u'goals_scored': 0,
 u'id:0,
 u'history: 
#single game data ( there are multiple games)
[{u'assists': 0,
    u'attempted_passes': 0,
    u'big_chances_created': 0,
    u'big_chances_missed': 0,
    u'bonus': 0,
    u'bps': 0,
    u'clean_sheets': 0,
    u'clearances_blocks_interceptions': 0,
    u'completed_passes': 0,
    u'creativity': u'0.0',
    u'dribbles': 0,
    u'ea_index': 0,
    u'element': 1,
    u'errors_leading_to_goal': 0,
    u'errors_leading_to_goal_attempt': 0,
    u'fixture': 31,
    u'fouls': 0,
    u'goals_conceded': 0,
    u'goals_scored': 0,
    u'ict_index': u'0.0',
    u'id': 1616,
    u'influence': u'0.0',
    u'key_passes': 0,
    u'kickoff_time': u'2016-09-10T14:00:00Z',
    u'kickoff_time_formatted': u'10 Sep 15:00',
    u'loaned_in': 0,
    u'loaned_out': 0,
    u'minutes': 0,
    u'offside': 0,
    u'open_play_crosses': 0,
    u'opponent_team': 13,
    u'own_goals': 0,
    u'penalties_conceded': 0,
    u'penalties_missed': 0,
    u'penalties_saved': 0,
    u'recoveries': 0,
    u'red_cards': 0,
    u'round': 4,
    u'saves': 0,
    u'selected': 8072,
    u'tackled': 0,
    u'tackles': 0,
    u'target_missed': 0,
    u'team_a_score': 1,
    u'team_h_score': 2,
    u'threat': u'0.0',
    u'total_points': 0,
    u'transfers_balance': -449,
    u'transfers_in': 183,
    u'transfers_out': 632,
    u'value': 49,
    u'was_home': True,
    u'winning_goals': 0,
    u'yellow_cards': 0}, ... next game data]
```

Comment: could you post sample data for one player

Comment: Perhaps look into [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use Python as the storage solution here? A relational database would appear a better way to store the data, you then have a range of choices (including Python) for interacting with the data.

Comment: Depending on your purposes, The R Statistical Programming Language may be more appropriate. A Data Frame would, I assume, nullify the question regarding data storage here.

Comment: @Navidad20 thanks for your reply. Have posted data but it is a little opaque so added some explanations too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "However I'm not sure whether this will translate well into a pandas
>   dataframe, which is ultimately where I would like to perform most of
>   my analysis."

See:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you